# How to add export functionality in Magento 2 new grid system

Tags: grid, magento2, export

In Magento 1 I could add export functionality to any admin grid I create by adding this

```
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportXml', Mage::helper('helper_alias')->__('Excel XML'));
```

in the `_prepareColumns` of the grid block and then implementing the `expotCsvAction` and `exportXmlAction` in my admin controller.

How can I achieve the same result in Magento 2 in the new grid system? (the one that uses ui components and knockout js for rendering). Example, the products grid, the cms pages grid.
Or better yet, is this even possible?

Comment: Better you can explore 'CustomerImportExport' module. it's working for my own module. If you need then I can create a sample module for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't need (for now) a full import/export functionality. I just want to a grid export to all my custom grids. Kandy's answer solves it elegantly.

Comment: No need to explore all module, only Controller and admin layout. Both are exportCsv and exportXml, only.

Comment: <exportButton class="Magento\Ui\Component\ExportButton" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/export" displayArea="dataGridActions"> <settings> <options> <option name="cvs" xsi:type="array"> <item name="value" xsi:type="string">csv</item> <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">CSV</item> <item name="url" xsi:type="string">mymodule/product/export</item> </option> </options> </settings> </exportButton>

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [sales/orders grid](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Sales/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml) as example.

*exportButton* ui component responsible for UI

```
<exportButton name="export_button">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_order_grid.sales_order_grid.sales_order_columns.ids</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</exportButton>
```

where `selectProvider`  is component responsible for selections data.

By default csv/xml options available and leads to `\Magento\Ui\Controller\Adminhtml\Export\GridTo{Csv,Xml}` action that export all selected data from data provider.

Comment: damn...how did I miss that? I don't even need a custom action anymore for the export. thanks.

Comment: Does this still work in 2.1?

Comment: It doesn't work on Products grid, gives error on qty columns, fixed it get complaint about interfaces.

Comment: anyone found a way?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\Mymodule\Controller\Adminhtml\Product;

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\Directory\WriteInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Magento\Ui\Model\Export\ConvertToCsv;
use Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory;
use VendorName\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class Export extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
/**
 * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory
 */
protected $resultForwardFactory;

/**
 * Massactions filter
 *
 * @var Filter
 */
protected $filter;

/**
 * @var MetadataProvider
 */
protected $metadataProvider;
/**
 * @var WriteInterface
 */
protected $directory;
/**
 * @var ConvertToCsv
 */
protected $converter;
/**
 * @var FileFactory
 */
protected $fileFactory;



public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\ForwardFactory $resultForwardFactory,
    Filter $filter,
    Filesystem $filesystem,
    ConvertToCsv $converter,
    FileFactory $fileFactory,
    \Magento\Ui\Model\Export\MetadataProvider $metadataProvider,
    \VendorName\Mymodule\Model\ResourceModel\Product $resource,
    CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
) {
    $this->resources = $resource;
    $this->filter = $filter;
    $this->_connection = $this->resources->getConnection();
    $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
    $this->metadataProvider = $metadataProvider;
    $this->converter = $converter;
    $this->fileFactory = $fileFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
    $this->resultForwardFactory = $resultForwardFactory;
    $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
}

/**
 * export.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Forward
 */
public function execute()
{
    try {
    $selected = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');
    if($selected) {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
    }else {
        $collection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->collectionFactory->create());
    }
    $ids = $collection->getAllIds();

    $component = $this->filter->getComponent();
    $this->filter->prepareComponent($component);
    $dataProvider = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider();
    $dataProvider->setLimit(0, false);
    $searchResult = $component->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getSearchResult();
    $fields = $this->metadataProvider->getFields($component);
    $options = $this->metadataProvider->getOptions();
    $name = md5(microtime());
    $file = 'export/'. $component->getName() . $name . '.csv';
    $this->directory->create('export');
    $stream = $this->directory->openFile($file, 'w+');
    $stream->lock();
    $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getHeaders($component));

    foreach ($searchResult->getItems() as $document) {
        if( in_array( $document->getId(), $ids ) ) {
            $this->metadataProvider->convertDate($document, $component->getName());
            $stream->writeCsv($this->metadataProvider->getRowData($document, $fields, $options));
        }
    }
    $stream->unlock();
    $stream->close();
    return $this->fileFactory->create('export.csv', [
        'type' => 'filename',
        'value' => $file,
        'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
    ], 'var');


    }catch (\Exception $e){

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just updating Kandy's answer here

in your ui_component listing file you just need to add below one line for export

```
<exportButton name="export_button"/>
```

Make sure you add above line in `listingToolbar` node